# How to get lines in to colums? SExt Query

Tags: sql, datetime, ms-access, sum, pivot

Here the query i wrote very simple.

```
 SELECT        GeneralLedger, YEAR(ReportingDate) AS jaar, MONTH(ReportingDate) AS periode, SUM(AmountDCDebit - AmountDCCredit) AS Saldo
FROM            dbo.GeneralLedgerBalances
GROUP BY GeneralLedger, YEAR(ReportingDate), MONTH(ReportingDate)
HAVING        (YEAR(ReportingDate) = 2020)
```

the result i get is

[image]

How ever i wan to get this result:

[image]

I want to get the periods in a column How can I change my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    GeneralLedger, 
    YEAR(ReportingDate) AS jaar, 
    SUM(IIF(MONTH(ReportingDate) =  1, AmountDCDebit - AmountDCCredit, 0)) AS Saldo01,
    SUM(IIF(MONTH(ReportingDate) =  2, AmountDCDebit - AmountDCCredit, 0)) AS Saldo02,
    ...
    SUM(IIF(MONTH(ReportingDate) = 12, AmountDCDebit - AmountDCCredit, 0)) AS Saldo12
FROM dbo.GeneralLedgerBalances
WHERE (YEAR(ReportingDate) = 2020)
GROUP BY GeneralLedger, YEAR(ReportingDate)
```

Comment: Hi,if i try this i receive  this error: Error in list of function arguments: 'SUM' not recognized.
Unable to parse query text.

Comment: @Barendrecht . . . You are doing something wrong.  `SUM()` is a very common SQL function.

Comment: @Barendrecht: you are missing commas between the `SUM()` expressions...